# Is it possible to cast a Tensor<TInt32> in Java to a double and other native Java variable types?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to TensorFlow and I cannot seem to find how to do this despite extensive searching online. I want to load the TensorFlow model I have built into Java to set some variable values, which in this case, is a double. Is there a good way of going about this?

I have looked at the TensorFlow copyTo() function but it doesn't seem relevant. I have found no relevant search results when trying to do this casting as well.

Here is the code snippet of what I am trying to do:

```html
try(SavedModelBundle b = SavedModelBundle.load("/somePath", "serve")) {
    Session s = b.session();
    Tensor<TInt32> x = TInt32.scalarOf(1);
    Tensor<TInt32> y = TInt32.scalarOf(2);
        
    Tensor<TInt32> result = (Tensor<TInt32>) s.runner().feed("x", x).feed("y", y).fetch("ans").run().get(0);

    // I know this won't work but do whatever is needed to convert to a double
    this.ExampleDouble = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to retrieve the output tensor(s) with their [expected](https://github.com/tensorflow/java/blob/a4f32dcc552343d069208757ab6d89d1d0ca793d/tensorflow-core/tensorflow-core-api/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/Tensor.java#L201) type.

If your model is returning an 32-bit integer (like it seems to do given your example), then you should do the following:

```java
// Also note all resources that should be protected by a try-with-resource block...
try(SavedModelBundle model = SavedModelBundle.load("/somePath", "serve");
    Tensor<TInt32> x = TInt32.scalarOf(1);
    Tensor<TInt32> y = TInt32.scalarOf(2)) {

  // Let's use the new functional API to instead of invoking the session directly
  Map<String, Tensor<?>> inputTensors = new HashMap() {{
    put("x", x);
    put("y", y);
  }};
  try (Tensor<TInt32> result = model.call(inputTensors).get("ans").expect(TInt32.DTYPE)) {
    this.ExampleDouble = (double)(result.data().getInt());
  }
}
```

It is a bit surprising though that the datatype of the model output is a 32-bit integer if you know that it is returning a double floating value. Make sure to request the right datatype, as found in the model signature, or the cast will fail (if it is a double, then the expected datatype might be `TFloat64.DTYPE`).

You can look at the signatures of your model by calling `model.signatures()`